# How to remove image file system in ionic 2?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, ionic-framework, ionic2

I am trying to remove the image from the gallery.

An error displays:

> Wrong type for parameter "uri" of resolveLocalFileSystemURI: Expected
>   String, but got Array.

**Code**

```
let data:Array<{ imgUrl: string, fileName: string }>;
    data = new Array();
    let j = 0;
    for(let test of pathimg){
      data.push({imgUrl:pathimg,fileName:filename[j]+'.png'});
      j++;
    }

for(let test of data){    
    this.file.removeFile(test.imgUrl, test.fileName).then(_ =>
        console.log('deleted succesfully')).catch(err =>
            console.log('cannot delete'));
}
```

Comment: You have provided very limited information but my guess here is that test.imgUrl is an array, where you need to add the string of the URI...

Comment: @VeldMuijz update code check i m convert string but not work

Comment: Show me what is `pathimg` and `filename`

Comment: @VeldMuijz succesfully[{"imgUrl":["file:///data/user/0/com.pmtx.schooltune/files/cj3iNgR11Pth3LspEu3wSM/18fb5a7ee591a3a1195d1a119fd1a6be.png"],"fileName":"18fb5a7ee591a3a1195d1a119fd1a6be.png"}]

Comment: ImgUrl is an Array, the value is an Array. You can see that because it is surrounded with `[` and `]`